# How do I place an image inside a <div> depending on the image dimensions?

Tags: javascript

I am looking to place images inside a div depending on what the images dimensions are. For example:

- Div1: Any images with the width > 600 goes here.
- Div2: Any images with the height >800 goes here.
- img1 Dimensions = width:601px; height: 300px; Place this image on
  Div1.
- img2 Dimensions = width:400px; height: 850px; Place this image inside
  Div2.

How can I do that using javascript?

here is how I am attempting to do it.

```
#Div1{
    width:600px;
    height:auto;
}
#Div2{
    width:auto;
    height:600px;
}
```

```
var imageUrl = new Array();
    imageUrl[2] = '<img id="checkfunctionfirst" src="img1.jpg">'
    imageUrl[3] = '<img id="checkfunctionfirst" src="img2.jpg">'
    imageUrl[5] = '<img id="checkfunctionfirst" src="img3.jpg">'

function checkfunctionfirst () {

    for(i=0;i<=imageUrl.length;i++){
        if(imageUrl[i].width>600){
            //place this image on Div1
        } 
        if(imageUrl[i].height>800){
            //place this image on Div2
        }

    }    
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking what to put inside your if statements?

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues and questions around your code example, so it’s hard to point out where to start and what to change. But I’ll give you an example on how your code could work instead, I hope it helps:

```
var imageUrl = ['img1.jpg','img2.jpg','img3.jpg'], // the images to use
    i = 0, len = imageUrl.length, img; // some vars used later

for( ; i<len; i++ ) { // loop through the image URLs

    img = new Image(); // create a new image

    img.onload = function() { // you need this to get the width/height

        if ( this.height > 800 ) { // "this" is the Image element
            document.getElementById('Div2').appendChild(this); // append to to the div
        } else if ( this.width > 600 ) {
            document.getElementById('Div1').appendChild(this);
        }
    };
    img.src = imageUrl[i]; // give the Image element a source
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, if the image meets the criteria, add the image tag to the end of a string...

```
var div1Cont = "";
if(imageUrl[i].width>600){
    div1Cont += imgUrl[i];
}
```

and then after the for statement, put that string within your div..

```
document.getElementById("Div1").innerHTML = div1Cont;
```

And then similar with your div 2.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to see that you are trying to do things yourself without jquery or any other plugins. You are the man!

First of all I should say for every image element you should wait until the image is loaded to find out the dimension of that element. I think you should handle the `"onload"` event in javascript. It fires whenever the image is completely loaded. If you have the static dimensions you should set them though `"width"` and `"height"` properties in the `"style"` attribute of each `"img"` element.

After you had all the dimensions, I believe that your code seems to be fine and you should use the `"appendChild"` method to append `"img"` elements to `"div"` elements.

Cheers